# How to store product tags in database for better indexing and searching

Tags: mysql, database, tags

My website deals with two types:

1. Products
2. Services

All functionalities are same for Products and Services are mostly same.

For this, I need to store tags for both products and services.

Please guide me to a way to store these tags in db, so that the products/services can be searched better, I can get popular/unpopular tags.

please let me know if you need more clarifications.

Thanks
Nivesh

Comment: Do you have any ideas? What is your problem with those ideas? Where exactly did things go wrong? Please try something before asking for help.

Comment: I need to know about the table structure for these. I am thinking of 2 more tables for all this. One is tags and other is products_tags. Is it okay? I am confused that what should be the best way to do all this.

Comment: Since you probably want N:N relations with any number of products/services having any number of tags, that is the normal approach, yes.

Comment: So that is fine ? Should i proceed with that ?